# How can i encoding in UTF-8 a Oracle SQL Developper Table

Tags: sql, oracle, encoding

I'm working on a university project with Oracle SQL Developper. I'm working with french adress but i have the problem of encoding.[image: As you can see in the print screen]

How can I change the encoding for oracle SQL table ?

I would like to have for example in line 9: "rue de béthune"

Thanks in advance,
François

I change the encoding in Tools --> Environnement --> UTF_8 but that didn't worked :(

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Regarding "How can i change the encoding for oracle SQL table?", see [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011) but I don't think this will change anything. What do you get from `SELECT DUMP(LIGNE_2, 1016) FROM ...`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit for the line 11 i obtain this : Typ=1 Len=17 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: 72,75,65,20,64,65,20,42,c3,83,c2,a9,74,68,75,6e,65 and for the line 6 i obtain : NULL

Comment: Again, please provide your data as text - not as screenshot!  Line 6 and 11 have `NULL` for LIGNE_2, so it is nonsense if you refer to these lines.